# In Excel Move a Cells contents, across one column, up one row. assign a macro button

Tags: excel, vba, button, macros

this is probably a very basic question but I am puzzled!

In Excel I have a word in Cell A9, I want to move that word to Cell B8.
I want to be able to click a macro button that does this "move across 1, then up 1" action.

( I have lots of random cells that contain data that should be elsewhere; always across1, up1, and I just want a button to move them for me individually, rather than me clicking and dragging each one)

Heres hoping someone can help me :) thankyou in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Attach this macro to a button. whenever you click on the button, the selected cell will then be cut and pasted as required.

```
Sub MoveUpAndRightOne()

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1)
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Select

End Sub
```